Constructing a triangle given two sides and the median of the third side
I'm working through Euclid's “Elements” Redux by Callahan (The 13 June 2024 edition), but I have a problem demonstrating the exercise. This time is one on page 111, specifically the number 5. The problem says:


Construct a triangle given two sides and the median of the third side.


I would like to know if someone could give me a clue. Likewise, if I can't find the answer, I will ask for a pious soul who will teach me how to prove it.

Apollonius' Theorem gives a rather uncomplicated relation between the sides and median of a triangle. This could provide the basis for a construction.

One approach is create 3 concentric circles on $A$ with the radii of both sides and the median, pick an arbitrary point $B$ on the outer circle (which cannot be the median), and dilate the inner or middle circle that is a side by $B(\frac{1}{2})$. Where this intersects the other circle is the median point in question relative to $B$, for the corresponding intersection with the other circle is twice the distance and must be $C$.

However, if you are in chapter 1 of that book, probably it is likely the construct is a parallelogram: use Euclid I.22 to construct a triangle with the two sides ($AB, AC$) and twice the median as the third side ($BC$), bisect the third side at $D$ and extend $AD=DA'$ then by parallelogram properties $\triangle{ABA'}$ is the required triangle.


Thanks a lot!! I'm still processing the circle demonstration. I don't understand how the circle at point M got there and how it is one of the other dilated circles. In my understanding, the circle with radius AC is positioned in the middle of AB as the center and then its radius is halved, isn't it? I still blame my lack of understanding on English, hahaha.

@CarlosJulioIslasBustamante - the first answer is a taste of what lies ahead for you, it is fine if it does not make sense yet. Once you have become comfortable with books 1-6 of Euclid, if you continue studying, you will eventually encounter framings of geometry via transformations. A dilatation (also called dilation) is nothing more than magnifying or shrinking the entire plane by a certain factor about a certain point. $B(0.5)$ means that everything shrinks halfway towards $B$. The little circle intersecting at $M$ is just the inner circle shrunk halfway towards $B$.
